# How can I match text that precedes an `<a>` tag then return the `<a>` node?

Tags: html, regex, parsing, go

I have the following, where I am trying to only capture the second case, where the text matches `But I want this one here`. Currently, it captures both cases.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func getTag(doc *html.Node, tag string) []*html.Node {
    var nodes []*html.Node
    var crawler func(*html.Node)
    crawler = func(node *html.Node) {
        if node.Type == html.ElementNode && node.Data == tag {
            nodes = append(nodes, node)
            return
        }
        for child := node.FirstChild; child != nil; child = child.NextSibling {
            crawler(child)
        }
    }
    crawler(doc)
    return nodes
}

func main() {
    doc, _ := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(testHTML))
    nodes := getTag(doc, "a")

    var buf bytes.Buffer
    w := io.Writer(&buf)
    for i, node := range nodes {
        html.Render(w, node)
        if i < (len(nodes) - 1) {
            w.Write([]byte("\n"))
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(buf.String())
}

var testHTML = `<html><body>
I do not want this link here <a href="blah">link text</a>
But I want this one here <a href="blah blah">more link text</a>
</body></html>`
```

This outputs:

`<a href="blah">link text</a>
<a href="blah blah">more link text</a>`

I would like to match specific text that precedes an `<a>` tag and, if it matches, return the `<a>` node. For instance, pass in `But I want this one here` and it returns `<a href="blah blah">more link text</a>`. I've been told to not parse html with regex but now I am stuck.

Comment: Regex is badly suited for this. Use a DOM parser instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: The answer there says not to use regex

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is not recommended to attempt using regex for this sort of issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually pretty close, because you are already using a proper parser (`html.Parse` from `golang.org/x/net/html`).

The trick here is that the various elements of the page are bound together conveniently, so you can use your existing `crawler` code with a later filtering function, if you like.  (You could instead combine the filtering directly into the crawler.)

Each `n *html.ElementNode` is preceded by something unless it's the initial element in a block (first of a document or first child node), and that *something* is in `n.PrevSibling`.  If its type is `html.TextNode` you have a sequence of the form:

```
some text<a ...>thing</a>
```

and you can examine the "some text" in the previous node:

```
func wanted(re *regexp.Regexp, n *html.Node) bool {
    if n.PrevSibling == nil || n.PrevSibling.Type != html.TextNode {
        return false
    }
    return re.MatchString(n.PrevSibling.Data)
}
```

This won't be perfect, because you could have, e.g.:

```
text <font></font> broken <font></font>up<a href="lastlink">last link</a>
```

and the code will try to match against the string `up`, when you probably should put the text together into `text broken up` and pass that to the matcher.  See more complete example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/mHTkSwlcCNA).